# How do i use a variable to construct a sequence?

Tags: bash

This, of course, works:

```
$ echo {1..5}
1 2 3 4 5
```

But when i attempt to substitute the number `5` with a variable, this no longer works:

```
$ f=5; echo {1..$f}
{1..5}

$ f=5; echo {1..${f}}
{1..5}

$ f=5; echo {1..f}
{1..f}
```

Is there a way to substitute the number within a variable before the `{#..#}` construct is parsed?

Comment: Bash do brace expansion _before_ it does variable expansion.  So, no, in bash, you cannot do what you want.  Use `seq` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way:

```
:~# f=5 ; eval echo {1..$f}
1 2 3 4 5
```

Alternative:

```
:~# f=5 ; echo `seq 1 $f`
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Please explain why `eval` is nessecary, just fixing the script doesn't help anyone learn what they are doing wrong.

Comment: Who said it is needed? This is one of the options to solve the problem - as you can see the second solution uses the sequence seq.